# How to increase the characters per line when using kubectl exec

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

first of all any help is appreciated

I want execute a command in a container and I execute:

```
kubectl exec -ti busybox bash
```

but if I input about 70 characters in bash and then I get truncated output and line broken anyway lead to unreadable.

is there a way to increase the characters per line when using kubectl exec?

```
Environment (also see manifests for more detailed info):

Centos 7.0.1406 

Kubernetes: 1.2.0 

etcd: 2.3.7 

flannel: 0.5.3 

docker:1.10.3
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This will be supported in the upcoming Kubernetes 1.4 release (if you're interested, see its [fix](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/25273)).

Comment: thx!
and i have resolve by add env COLUMNS=$COLUMNS LINES=$LINES  before bash
`kubectl exec -ti busybox env COLUMNS=$COLUMNS LINES=$LINES bash`

Comment: @lufeng:  Many thanks for this fix!  I've added this to my list of things I need to remember [here](https://coderwall.com/p/qtk07q/fix-terminal-rows-columns-and-type-when-using-old-versions-of-kubectl-exec)